# Control the past, control the future in a different time-stream?

Tags: plot-explanation, terra-nova

In the first episode of the TV series *Terra Nova,* Maddy and her little sister see [The Probe](http://terranova.wikia.com/wiki/The_Probe). It's the first item that they send back into the past, but *they never found it in the future*.

I believe she says that because The Probe was never found in the future, they are in some other sort of time-stream - *meaning that there would be no risk to the future if history was altered.*

So what happens in Terra Nova doesn't have an impact on the future? 
Yet in one of the last episodes Lucas Taylor states:

> Control the past, control the future.

What does he mean by that if whatever happens in Terra Nova doesn't have an impact on the future?

Comment: Bad writing and plot hole ? I was myself conviced they were in the future, long after the end of the mankind.

Answer (score 2):

This phrase must not be taken in a butterfly effect way.

You can't change what already happened in the future.
But the "past" is where the last of resources are.

It's like saying "Control the oil in middle east, control the world"